# Using a frame with SVG can't make it grow

Tags: svg, responsive-design, responsive

I have a frame in SVG that I need to make it grow (responsive) in different devices but I can't make it work.

it driving me crazy, here is the html:

```
<body>
    <article>
      <h1>Test SVG FRAME</h1>
      <h4>SUB TITLE FRAME SVG</h4>
      <p>
        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
        fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae,
        ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam
        egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend
        leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
        malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat
        vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet
        quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat
        eleifend leo.
      </p>
    </article>
  </body>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
article {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://showcase.cupra.de/svg/Header-Slider_FormNew.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 35rem;
}

p {
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

and here is the codesanbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cookies-0l0px?file=/styles.css:33-327

I'm follow this article -> https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/06-using-svg-svg-background-image/

if someone can give me an advice and hint, thanks.

Comment: does adding preserveAspectRatio="none" to the SVG root element help?

Comment: Also try removing the `width="776.758" height="335.682"` from the SVG's `<svg>` tag.

Comment: I think Paul's suggestion above is prudent. I would change those values in the svg itself to width = "100%" height = "100%" to specify that the svgs viewbox should always fully expand to the dimensions of whatever container its inside of.